# Mono 3.2.1: PCL targetting .Net 4.5 is missing LinkedList

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin-studio

I'm building an app using Xamarin.iOS, Mono 3.2.1 and Visual Studio 2012.
In a Portable Class Library targetting .Net 4.5 (profile 49), I'm using a LinkedList in a LRU cache implementation (see [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Utilities/LRUCache.cs)).

This al runs fine when building in VS2012 (on PC), but as soon as I try to build this project in Xamarin Studio (on Mac), the build fails with this error:

> The type or namespace name 'LinkedList' could not be found. Are you
>   missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)

I tried to add a reference to `System.Collections`, but then got the error:

> The imported type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' is defined multiple times (CS0433)

Any help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people at Xamarin pointed me to the Alpha-channel.

It is now running as it is supposed to, using Mono 3.2.2 (and Xamarin Studio 4.1.10 build 14).